# Grabbing articles from my Wordpress site then using that in a UITableView?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview

As the title says I'm currently trying to grab the posts from my Wordpress site and then load it into a UITableView so It can be viewed like that. How would this be done? Im assuming Im going to have to use XML but how..? I'd rather try RSS if I can? Or what ever way works!
Thank you so much for helping!

Answer (score 0):

RSS is the way to go... You can use a XML Parser to parse the RSS feed and display them. I'm not sure whether you are aware of this.
http://iphone.wordpress.org